# Chef Knife AWS EC2 instances elastic IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I will need to spin multiple elastic ips to create accounts from sites.

I plan to do this using either aws ec2 API or building chef cookbooks.

I wonder whether it's a good solution to use chef cookbooks to do this task.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with multiple accounts?  As soon as I hear people talk about multiple elastic IP addresses, I feel people are going about something the "wrong" way ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would generally avoid using Chef for scripting changes to your AWS resources. If you are looking for more automation than the EC2 API provides, you might like to take a look at CloudFormation.